# Peano existence theorem: counterexample when $f$ is not continuous

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Peano's existence theorem states that for any continuous function $f$ any initial value problem for the ODE 
$$y'=f(x,y),y(x_0)=y_0$$
has at least one solution on some closed interval $[x_0-\epsilon,x_0+\epsilon]$.

Is there a nice example of $f$ not being continuous so that we can't find a solution to the initial value problem on any neighborhood of the initial value pair $(x_0,y_0)$?

Comment: Try $f(x,y)=f(x)=0$ for $x\neq 0$, $f(x)=1$ for $x=0$, with $x_0=0$

Comment: Try $f(x,y) = 1$ for $y \le 0$ and $f(x,y) = -1$ for $y >0$.

Comment: Or more ornate than the last example, $\ddot x+x = -sign(\dot x)$ and any other example from the "sliding mode" theory.